# Не работает скрипт после подгрузки страницы AJAX-ом

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здрасте, есть файл index.php, в нем при нажатии на кнопку подключается другой файл (include) в котором есть поле (input). При отжатии клавиши должен срабатывать скрипт, но этого не происходит. Пытался решить проблему используя "on" и тд., но не выходит.

```
$('.input').on('keyup', function(){
     var value = $('.input').val();
     alert(value);
});
```

Сам input

```
 echo '<input type="number" class="input" min="1" max="99999" name="price" value="1"><br />';
```

Comment: `$(document).on('keyup', '.input', function(){ ...`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.